# Nodejs not sending data in Reactjs functional component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When you call it in http://localhost:9000/testApi, it works fine.

testAPI.js

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.send("API is working fine");
});

module.exports = router;
```

But Calling in ReactJS functional component leads to nothing

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import TopicCard from './TopicCard.js'
import './HomePage.css'

function HomePage() {

const [apiResponse,setApiResponse] = useState('Loading..')
const url = "http://localhost:9000/"

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url).then(res => setApiResponse(res.data))
}, [])

return (
    <> 
        <h1>Choose a topic to learn {apiResponse}</h1>
    </>
);
```

Console.log gives this

> Promise {}[[Prototype]]: Promise [[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
> [[PromiseResult]]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position
> 0

While the Class Component is working perfectly fine

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { apiResponse: "" };
    }
    
    callAPI() {
        fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
    }
    
    componentWillMount() {
        this.callAPI();
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="App-intro">;{this.state.apiResponse}</p>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No differences are between functional and class-based components.

##### The Problem

You forgot to parse your response as a text in the `fetch` method.

##### The Solution

parse your data as a `text` and then store it on your state variable

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(URL)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => setApiResponse(res))
        .catch(err => console.warn(err))
}, [])
```

**Note:** don't forget to use `catch` method for your asynchronous fetch API.

##### Explanation

When your data (API call response) is in standard JSON format, you need to parse them with `.json()` method, and usually, a `data` property holds the whole response, but in your case (with a text as a response) it's not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you confusing routes / end points with file names? testAPI.js is your file name. It's not your endpoint.

You call:

```
const url = "http://localhost:9000/testAPI"

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url).then(res => setApiResponse(res.data))
}, [])
```

But your endpoint is - a forward slash '/'  i.e. the root (not ROUTE) :

```
router.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.send("API is working fine");
});
```

Try changing to this:

```
 const url = "http://localhost:9000/"
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url).then(res => setApiResponse(res.data))
    }, [])
```

If you want to fetch const url = "http://localhost:9000/testAPI" from react then change the endpoint to:
const url = "http://localhost:9000/testAPI" else server won't know of it.

Comment: http://localhost:9000/testAPI is giving proper response. But in Reactjs, it is returning undefined

Comment: As I said this const url = "http://localhost:9000/testAPI" is NOT the end point. You need to call this const url = "http://localhost:9000/" since you built this in you testAPI file.

Comment: In your react DO NOT call "http://localhost:9000/testAPI" BUT call "http://localhost:9000/"

Comment: Also try to log res in console and log res.data. Are they undefined?

Comment: Yes they are undefined

Comment: OK follow my previous insturctions.

Comment: fetch("http://localhost:9000/").then(res => setApiResponse(res.data))

Comment: Still not working

Comment: `fetch(url)` resolves to a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) which doesn't have a `data` property. It should be `fetch(url).then(res => res.text()).then(setApiResponse)`